# How to edit/update form?

Tags: php, html

I'm having a hard time on how to update/edit my code.

PHP:

```
 <?php
    require("config.php");


    $link =mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db)OR die(mysql_error());


    if (  isset($_POST['newhotel']));
    {
        $newhotel = $_POST['newhotel'];
        //$BIL    = $_POST['BIL'];
        $query    = "UPDATE hotels set hotel='$_POST[newhotel]' where hotel='$hotel'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        header( "refresh:0; url=view.php" );
        }
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
New Hotel: <br  />
<input  type="text" name="newhotel"/><BR />

Address: <br />
<textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><BR />

<input require name="" type="submit" value="Update "/><input name="" type="reset" value="Clear" />
<p></p>
</form>
```

I know that my code is wrong. Can someone provide me a hint so that i can rectify my problem. thank you

Comment: You don't execute the select query for one. There is no input with name edit for another. Mixing APIs too. And that semicolon after isset is tricking you

Comment: im sorry but i dont quite understand, cau you please explain it to me?

Comment: you need edit form for already existing hotel is it ?

Comment: Your select is missing `mysqli_query()`, so the query is never executed. `if(isset($_POST['newhotel']));`  that semicolon isn't supposed to be there. There is no element in your form with `name="edit"`. Then theres `mysql_error()`, which doesn't work with `mysqli_*`. Basically you should start over and read a tutorial on HTML forms, perhaps here: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 1):

This is your HTML form:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    New Hotel: <br  />
    <input  type="text" name="newhotel"/><BR />

    Address: <br />
    <textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><BR />

    <input  name="sub" type="submit" value="Update "/>
    <input name="" type="reset" value="Clear" />
    <p></p>
    </form>
```

Here method is  post. When the user fills in this form and hits the submit button, the action.php page is called.so you code will be

**edit.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

output would be like

```
Array
(
    [newhotel] => asasa
    [address] => sasa
    [sub] => Submit
)
```

here you have only post values and there is no field for edit so below code is wrong.from where you get this $_GET values

```
if( isset ( $_GET['edit']))
{
    $BIL = $_GET['edit'];
    $query = "SELECT * from hotels where hotel='$hotel'";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
}
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply but it seems that when i used your code, my existing data still cant be edit/update. Any tips?

Comment: @SyedShahrulShafiq - did you echo $_POST?

Comment: I've no idea what to do so i followed this one guy from youtube and i tried to do what he did but to no avail, and yes i did $_POST, but i still cant edit/update existing value, any tips?

Comment: @SyedShahrulShafiq -it seems your edit query is wrong.still edit is inside if( isset ( $_GET['edit']))
{} ? from where you get this get values?according to your post you can't get get value.you get only post values.please share your you tube link

Comment: i got it from here; youtube.com/watch?v=Hw1MwUlekeo. Basiclly i've no idea on how to do coding for edit, ive been in and out many forums and have tried many codes but to no avail.